# property of complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I can't solve the following problem: 
Let $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + ... + a_0$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n \ge 1$. Assume that there exist $j \in \{0, 1, ... n-1\}$ such that $a_j \neq 0$. Prove that there exist a point $\zeta$ such that $|\zeta| = 1$ and $|p(\zeta)| \gt 1$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recall that 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(j-k)\theta } d\theta=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if}\,\, j\ne k \\ 2\pi, & \text{if}\,\, j=k. \end{cases}
$$

Let $a_n=1$, then $p(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jz^j$. Then \begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} |p(e^{i\theta })|^2 d\theta &=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_je^{ij\theta}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \bar{a}_ke^{-ik\theta}\right)d\theta \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n a_j\bar{a}_k\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(j-k)\theta } d\theta \\
&=2\pi\sum_{j=0}^n |a_j|^2=2\pi\left(1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} |a_j|^2\right)\\
&>2\pi,\tag{1}
\end{align}
since there exist $j \in \{0, 1, ...\, , n-1\}$ such that $a_j \neq 0.$
Now assume $|p(z)|\le 1$ for all points with $|z|=1$.
Then $$
\int_0^{2\pi} |p(e^{i\theta })|^2 d\theta\le \int_0^{2\pi}  d\theta=2\pi,$$
which contradicts $(1)$. Therefore there exist a point $ζ$  such that $|\zeta| = 1$ and $|p(\zeta)| > 1$.